# Android application reference for starting real world development

Tags: java, android, mobile

I started serious development on Android recently. I know Java and introduced to Android SDK, but I haven't done any good projects in Android yet. Although I developed one or two applications for Android, I am not satisfied with my work as a programmer. I can't appreciate my application and its architecture very much. I feel referring some good real world applications will improve my app development very much. I know I can search on GitHub and like, and I had, but the results are plenty, and I am at a confusion on which ones I can pick.

Many of you people may came across good applications in your career, and I need your help now. Can you Please share the Android applications developed in Java that you feel had a good architecture, and well worth for study and reference?

Comment: While there are many nice Android apps, most are closed source, and therefore are not available for analysis of their architecture.

Comment: There's almost nothing Android-specific about good software design and architecture.

Answer (score 2):

[Commonsware](https://github.com/commonsguy) reusable components and the test apps that come with them are a good place to look at, another is the sample apps that come with Android SDK. Together they should give you enough to get started.

Comment: While I appreciate the vote of confidence, this isn't really what the OP is asking for. Most of my samples are just that -- samples -- not full-fledged apps.

Comment: Agreed, its just that as you said in above comment, most apps are closed source. So I thought it better to get started with some well designed sample apps, and the Android sample apps shipped with SDK, vs. having nothing to look at.

Comment: True enough. I just didn't want the OP to think that my samples were anything but samples. :-)